# How to get rid of blind sql injection?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

We are using jsf primefaces in the presentation layer and hibernate as the ORM tool.
While running a security tool to check the security level of our code, we are getting
few blind sql injection warnings.
I know the basic reason when this vulnurability comes.To confirm, I have checked most
of the queries written and found all of them follow the correct pattern of

```
    SELECT col  FROM table  WHERE col = :Identifier
```

And then we are using getNamedQuery to retrieve the query.To populate the identifier we
are using the setter methods.

The report generated by the security checking tool contains some
UI components id for   or  etc.
And it states the problem as

**The following changes were applied to the original request:
- Set the value of the parameter 'form:someDropDown_input' to '0%2B0%2B0%2B1'
- Set the value of the parameter 'form:someDropDown_input' to '12345%2B12345%2B1'**

Also in some other places it is showing the problem as

**The following changes were applied to the original request:
- Set the value of the parameter 'javax.faces.partial.execute' to '%40all%27+and+%27f%27%3D%27f'**

I am hardly understanding anything from the error reports.
So please guide me where the problem might be.

Comment: Are you sure this is an error report? The sentence "The following changes were applied..." more sounds like a log file (just saying what the security checking tool did). It doesn't sound like a security problem.

Comment: Yes it is printed exactly the way I have put in the report.The tool I think tries to tamper the user inputs.If it succeeds I think considers to be a problem.Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of results from "security tools", like the IBM AppScan you seem to be running are just guesswork. Blind SQL injection is a category of detections that is even less reliable than the average.

Since you're using parametrized queries, you're ok. Tell whoever runs this tool that this is a false positive. If they disagree, ask them to demonstrate you how this can be exploited.